# De-synonymize vibration, haptic-feedback

Tags: discussion, status-completed, retag-request

I don't know who or when, but [haptic-feedback](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/haptic-feedback) is currently a synonym of [vibration](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vibration).

Now, while haptic feedback *is* a vibration, it is quite separate and distinct from notification vibrations. (The lack of a tag wiki certainly doesn't help.) I don't think they should be synonyms. In fact, "vibration" should probably be [notification-vibration](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/notification-vibration) or similar.

Does anyone have a good argument for why these should stay synonyms? (Yes, I know it'll take touching every single question with [vibration](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vibration) to fix. I'm willing to do it.)

Comment: turning vibration into notification-vibration is a good idea

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That was me yesterday. There were only two questions so I didn't think the distinction was important.  (Side note, I renamed it from [haptic](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/haptic) to [haptic-feedback](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/haptic-feedback).)

I have no problem with them being separate though.  I unsynonymized and retagged the two questions, and added it to a third that needed it.